# PHP - Parsing iFrame from an HTML Page

Tags: php, html, iframe, server-side

Hey guys so I have a basic PHP application that loads a page with a video on it from one of those free TV streaming sites.  You set the episode, season and show you wish to view and the server application parses the HTML tag of the iFrame that contains that video.  The application works by parsing the HTML page with the PHP `preg_match_all()` method to get all occurrences of the `iFrame` HTML tag.  I use the following string as the pattern, `"/iframe .*\>/"`.  This works for about half of the video players on the site, but for some reason comes up dry with all of the others.

For examples the video at http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/novamov.php?id=huv5cpp5k8cia which hosted on a video site called `novamov` is easily parsed.  However, the video displayed at http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/gorillavid.php?id=8rerq4qpgsuw which is hosted on `gorillavid`, is not found by the `preg_match_all()` function despite it clearly being displayed in the HTML source when the element is inspected using chrome.  Why is my script no returning the proper results and why is this behaviour dependant on the video player the video is using? Please could someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; @$dom->loadHTML('yourURLHere');
$iframe = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach($iframe as $ifr){
  $ifrA[] = $ifr->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Now, the `$ifrA` Array should have your iframe src's.

Comment: I keep getting `Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in` when I try your approach